# How can a DEX protect itself against flash loan attacks?

Tags: security, decentralized-exchange, flash-loans

How can a DEX protect itself against flash loan attacks?

I've seen this code inside a function:

```
require(msg.sender == tx.origin, "probably a flash loan tx")
```

Is it effective?

Are there other ways?

Comment: That require will ensure that the caller is indeed a human and not a contract by ensuring that the origin is the sender. Though this will also exclude multisig users. And sometimes you'd want other protocols to be able to interact with your dex (that can be something valuable in web3)

Comment: @lain can you elaborate? examples?

Comment: With that require, the address that calls your contract must also be the origin (the sender that initiated the transaction call). User1 -> Your Contract will be a valid call, User1 -> Contract A -> Your Contract will fail.

Comment: @lain -> I know.